# Almost all files are locked in my Time Machine backups?

Tags: finder, time-machine, backup, file

For some reason my files are getting locked in my Time Machine backups. I mean, when you "Get Info" on one of them, the "Locked" box is checked. Folders are NOT locked, though.

Is this normal? This doesn't apply to just Apple files either (such as .pages). It's happening to .txt, .avi, .png, etc.

By now, almost all the files in my Time Machine backups are locked. So when I restore a folder, for instance, every single file in it is locked. This has definitely not been the case for me before.

Comment: i've edited my answer with a new suggestion- do you have Auto-Locking turned on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Disk Utility, select the partition of your drive with the Time Machine icon, and click Repair Disk to verify and fix any problems with permissions settings (see below image).

You *may also want to repeat the process* with Macintosh HD to be safe.

[image]

**update** Is this option checked for you? If not, it should be unchecked and Saved (from OSX Daily)

[image: (locked Time Machine files options]

Comment: Already ran it on Time Machine and found no problems. I'll try it on Macintosh HD as well, but this HD is about two days old (Apple Store replaced my iMac's HD).

Comment: @Gary Will it let you Repair Disk Permissions? Or is it similar to mine and ignores ownership?

Comment: No I can't Repair Disk Permissions on the Time Machine drive.

Comment: I don't have "Lock documents" enabled;  it does not even appear for me. I think the option disappeared in Mountain Lion. Also, I ran "Verify Disk" on every single partition I have on all internal and external drives, and no problems were found. (Except when running it on external drives, NOT the partitions, I got "Error: Partition map check failed because no slices were found." which seems to indicate that I can't boot from those, which is fine since they are for data only.)